# How to get a 'result summary' of the rows effectively showed?

Tags: views

I have a view, and in the Header section I have activated the 'Global: Result Summary'. My problem is that the line count does not take into account the user's permissions: for example if the view has 10 results, but the user can only see 5 (let's say the other 5 are not published), I see a page with 5 lines, but with a result-summary that says: Result 1-10 of 10. While it should be Result 1-5 of 5.
There is no need to tell the user that there are some results that he can't see. Is there a way to count the lines actually shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Global: Result Summary` should display only the total count of the actually output rows. You just need to set proper permissions and filter criteria for result summary to behave as you desire. For example, if you have `Content: Published (Yes)` filter in the `Filter criteria`, then the counter never will take unpublished nodes into account.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to set the Filter criteria: Published(Yes)  only for the anonymous user?

Comment: That's easily set on `admin/people/permissions` under the `View published content`. You could also play with `View own unpublished content` for authenticated users. If you need different Views filters for different roles, then just duplicate your view and replace them with each other on a template level depending who the current user is.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but could you please give me an example of how to implement the last part ('replace the view with each other on a template level depending who the current user is')?

Comment: Requires some coding. You need to identify the template of the page where your views is output and add if condition like: `if (user_is_anonymous()) { render your view for anonymous users here } else { render your views for authenticated users here }` if you have Drupal 7. For Drupal 8 use `\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @AltaGrade. The dual view solution worked perfectly, moreover, since the view was defined within a block, I could assign each view to the necessary role from the blocks section.